# avr-libc (void)__s at the end of a macro

Tags: c, gcc, avr-gcc

I am currently trying to figure out how avr-libc's [/util/atomic.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__atomic.html) implements its magic. So far I understood the use of the `__cleanup__` attribute to implement RIAA. I also understood the clever use of for loops to create a "block parameter". What I do not understand is the `(void)__s;` line at the end of the following functions.

```
static __inline__ void __iSeiParam(const uint8_t *__s)
{
    sei();
    __asm__ volatile ("" ::: "memory");
    (void)__s;
}

static __inline__ void __iCliParam(const uint8_t *__s)
{
    cli();
    __asm__ volatile ("" ::: "memory");
    (void)__s;
}
```

What is the last line of these functions for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions don't use their argument otherwise, so this use of the argument is there in order to eliminate "unused parameter" compiler warnings.

The cast to `(void)` is included because without that, most compilers would emit another warning, something like "expression result unused" (in the case of GCC, if I recall correctly).